# Threading not working with pygtk and always hangs

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, pygtk

Here is a small implementation of my problem. when i click "Press" button it hangs and some time it is not. How can overcome this hang ? 
here  is my code.

To install Sane "sudo apt-get install python-imaging-sane"

```
import gtk
import gtk.glade
import threading
import os
import sane
gtk.gdk.threads_init()
class process(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,main_object):
        self.main_object = main_object
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        sane_version = sane.init()
        sane_devices = sane.get_devices()
        gtk.threads_enter()
        self.main_object.pb.set_fraction(self.main_object.value)
        gtk.threads_leave()
        self.main_object.value = self.main_object.value + .1


class main():
    def __init__(self):
        #GUI
        window = gtk.Window()
        window.set_default_size(200,200)
        vbox = gtk.VBox(False,0)

        self.pb = gtk.ProgressBar()
        button = gtk.Button("Press me ")
        button.connect("clicked",self.fun_to_call)
        vbox.pack_end(self.pb)
        vbox.pack_end(button)
        button.show()
        self.pb.show()
        vbox.show()
        window.add(vbox)

        self.value = .1
        window.show()

    def fun_to_call(self,data=None):
        pro = process(self)
        pro.start()


main()
gtk.main()
```

Comment: Do you know whether the Sane bindings are thread safe?  If they don't do the `Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS`/`Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS` dance for any long running operations, then they will block Python code from executing in other threads.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [PyGTK FAQ on the subject](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq20.006.htp), it would seem that you're missing a step; (the whole FAQ entry is an interesting read though)

> ...you have to wrap your main loop with gtk.threads_enter()/gtk.threads_leave(), like this:
>
> gtk.threads_enter()
>   gtk.main()
>   gtk.threads_leave()

They also have some advice how to use `finally` to assure that `gtk.threads_leave()` is always run even if the code throws an exception.

Note though that using this kind of GUI threading isn't necessarily portable, some operating systems may have problems with a non main thread running GUI operations even with correct locking.

Answer (score 0):

The internals of the standard python implementation ("cpython") are not thread-safe.

So a lock (the [Global Interpreter Lock](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock)) is used to assure that only one python thread is running at a time. This lock is released e.g. when a running thread does I/O. But if the lock isn't released, the other threads won't get a chance to run.

I suspect that this is the source of the problem. It depends on the implementation of the sane bindings.

You could try using the [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) module instead of `threading`. Multiprocessing starts a completely different process for the long-running task, so it is not bound by the GIL. But you'd have to use the facilities provided by `multiprocessing` like `Queue` and `Pipe` to exchange information between the processes.